# Is there any way to send a mail from within my iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, email

I want to send an email from within my iPhone application, primarily because i don't want to quit my application. Is there ANY way to do that?

Solution:

1) I found this open source API which does that:
http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/

Anyone can write their own smtp client for this purpose. (If you can invest that much time - that is)

2) Use a web service to send the message details and handle message sending functionality at server end.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iPhone SDK 3.* has support sending email from with-in your application. Other than that, i found two other solutions that can be used as alternatives (though with iPhone SDK 3.*, not recommended):

1) I found this open source API which does that: http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/

Anyone can write their own smtp client for this purpose. (If you can invest that much time - that is)

2) Use a web service to send the message details and handle message sending functionality at server end.

Answer (score 1):

- Install [subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/getting.html#osx) on your Mac, as well as the command line tools, there are a variety of GUI wrappers available with a a little Googling.
- If you click the "source" tab on [that project](http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/) you'll see instructions for obtaining the source with subversion

Comment: Any Leopard Mac already comes with subversion installed on it.  He just needs to follow their instructions for the command line.

Comment: I have a leopard mac, and i tried that, but i think i'm missing something. i will play around with it over the weekend. thanks for the help.